# Seting value based on set to registry

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The goal of my situation/problem is I want to setValue of my getValue to a destination within the registry. I am not not too familiar with get/sets, so any help would be awesome. Let me know if you need anything else from me.

```
namespace RegistrySetter
{

public class Ironman : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> keypath { get; set; }
    public OutArgument<string> TextOut { get; set; }


    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        string KeyPath = this.keypath.Get(context);

        context.SetValue<string>(this.TextOut, KeyPath);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: One tip, don't name classes the same as your namespace ex. `Ironman`

Comment: I'm having trouble decipher what you're really asking, but properties are actually pretty simple... to get the value out of it, you can just do `string KeyPath = this.keypath`... to set a property, you can just do `this.TextOut = "output, yo!"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a registry value, you would probably use `Registry.GetValue`. The you just have to use the context to set the output argument.

An example:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

public class GetRegistryValue : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> KeyPath { get; set; }
    public OutArgument<string> TextOut { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        string keyPath = this.KeyPath.Get(context);
        string keyName = Path.GetDirectoryName(keyPath);
        string valueName = Path.GetFileName(keyPath);
        object value = Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, "");
        context.SetValue(this.TextOut, value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here KeyPath is something like: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\7-Zip\Path` where `Path` is actually the value name and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\7-Zip` is the key name.
If you want to set a registry value look into `Registry.SetValue`.

Comment: When using the Registry.SetValue I am struggling to figure out what the object for the value argument in here `string keyPath = this.keypath.Set(context,???);`

Comment: @Brandon I don't understand the question. The "value" argument for any setter method is going to be the value you want to put into some storage location. Also, most of the time setter methods do not return any thing.

Comment: Well when I thought a setter method was needed to create a registry key. Is this not correct? Could I do this within the getter?

Comment: @Brandon Do you want to write a value to the registry or read a value from the registry? If you want write a value, what is `TextOut` for?

Comment: I want to read a value with one activity(the Get method I am assuming). The other activity I want to be able to write to it (the Set method I am assuming).

Comment: @Brandon Ok then you need two activities, I have provided the Get activity. The Set activity is analogous but there will be two `InArgument<string>` properties, say `KeyPath` and `Value` and you use `Registry.SetValue`.